# Close child windows from postbacked parent window

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to close child windows which has been loaded by a parent window.
The child windows are opened by using `window.open()` method.
I need to close this child windows by clicking a logout button or close button which is in parent window.
My code:

```
    var childWin = [];
    //child window open event
    function child_open(url)
    {
        childWin[childWin.length] = window.open(url);
    }

    //a logout button or close button event
    function parent_close() 
    {
        for (i=0; i<childWin.length; i++) 
        {
            if (childWin[i] == null) return false;
            childWin[i].close();
        }
        window.close();
    }
```

This code is OK if the parent window don't postback to server.
When a postback occured in parent window,the value of variable(childWin) disappeared and I can't close child windows by this code.
Problem is - **want to close child windows even the parent postbacked.**
Is there a solution for this?
Thanks for all of your interests and replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array childWin will be cleared each time the page is loaded. So after post back there will be nothing in the array. Thats why the child windows are not getting closed.

A work around is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184186/window-reference-after-parent-page-changed)

Try something like this [not tested, and not sure it will work , just give a try :) ]

**Parent Window (all pages)**

```
var childStatus = {};
```

**Child Window**

```
var timerHandler,
    windowName = window.name,
    popupHandle = "";

funciton ChildCallBack()
{
  try
  {
    if(popupHandle == "" || popupHandle == null)
    {
       popupHandle = window.opener.childStatus[windowName];
       //ChildCallBack(); // no need of ChilCallBack here, since we already have timer
    }
    else
    {
       window.opener.childStatus[windowName] = popupHandle;        
    }
  }
  catch(e)
  {
  }
}

timerHandler = window.setInterval(ChildCallBack, 500);

function window_onclose()
{
  try
  { 
    window.clearInterval(timerHandler);
    window.opener.childStatus[windowName] = null;
  }
  catch(e)
  {
  }
}

window.onclose = window_onclose;
```

**Your Child window open function**

```
//child window open event
    function child_open(url)
    {
        var winHandle = window.open(url, "GIVE SOME UNIQUE NAME FOR EACH WINDOW HERE");
        winHandle.popupHandle = winHandle;
    }
```

**Your close button event**

```
//a logout button or close button event
    function parent_close() 
    {
        for (var key in childStatus)
        {
            if (childStatus[key] != null) 
            {
              childStatus[key].close();
            }
        }
        window.close();
    }
```

***Possible fix for query >> But, after a postback of child ,an error occurs in parent_close() (the value in childStatus[key] is not object and it can not do childStatus[key].close())***

Replace

```
timerHandler = window.setInterval(ChildCallBack, 100);
```

with

```
if(popupHandle == "" || popupHandle == null)
{
   // get the popupHandle from parent window
   popupHandle = window.opener.childStatus[windowName];
   timerHandler = window.setInterval(ChildCallBack, 100);
}
```

Comment: @kiranvj: It's work! After parent's postback,childStatus[] can maintain its values.But, after a postback of child ,an error occurs in parent_close() (the value in childStatus[key] is not object and it can not do childStatus[key].close())

Comment: Try the updated code above. You can also try this 1) Add try-catch wherever needed. 2) Increase the timer interval, we don't need it to be 100ms

Comment: @kiranvj: Thanks ,I got it!.I write `window.opener.childStatus[windowName] = popupHandle ;` after   **Null or "" Checking of popupHandle** ,if null,`get the popupHandle from parent window` as you describe above.You should update the answer to be best.

Comment: @kiranvj I put the checking(popupHandle is Null / "") within the ChildCallBack() function . Leave `timerHandler = window.setInterval(ChildCallBack, 100);`  with no checking as before.